# Object Equality in Typescript

Tags: typescript, equality

I'm creating a lib on vectors in typescript. My very first test failed:).

It's related to object equality in TypeScript/JavaScript but I can't find a way to make the test green. No object equality is mentioned in typescript's official doc http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#classes.

Could someone please give me a hand ?

This is the source code.

```
class Vector {
    x: number;
    y: number;

    constructor(x: number, y: number) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    add(that: Vector) {
        return new Vector(this.x + that.x, this.y + that.y);
    }
}

export = Vector;
```

Then I have a unit test on this class as follows

```
 var Vector = require("../lib/vector")

 describe("vector", function () {
  it("should add another vector", function () {
    var v1 = new Vector(1, 1);
    var v2 = new Vector(2, 3);
    expect(v1.add(v2)).toEqual(new Vector(3, 4));
  });
});
```

When executed obtains the following error

```
Failures: 
1) vector should add another vector
1.1) Expected Vector({ x: 3, y: 4 }) to be Vector({ x: 3, y: 4 }).
```

Comment: It works on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3VuGs/206/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your test case should work. [Here it is passing on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3VuGs/206/).

However, it seems your actual code was using `toBe()` instead of `toEqual()`, since the failure message says `"to be"` and not `"to equal"`:

> Expected Vector({ x: 3, y: 4 }) **to be** Vector({ x: 3, y: 4 }).

Using `toBe()` will check that the identity of the two objects are the same (ie `===`), which they obviously are not. You definitely want `toEqual()` which does a deep comparison of values.

Answer (score -3):

TypeScript object equality is the same as JavaScript object equality. This is because [TypeScript is just JavaScript](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/why-typescript.html).

Comment: This answer is unhelpful to the question.