# Equivalent of angular.equals in angular2

Tags: angularjs, object, angular, typescript

I am working on migration of angular 1 project to angular 2 . In angular 1 project I was using angular.equals for object comparison `angular.equals($ctrl.obj1, $ctrl.newObj);` , I searched online for equivalent method in angular 2 but could not find any matching result.

Comment: There is nothing like that in Angular2 AFAIK. There is only http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903941/object-equality-in-typescript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)

Comment: @Fiddles this question is more specific to Angular 2 and link which you posted is more generic java-script solution

Answer (score 25, accepted):

@Günter Yes you are right there is no equivalent in angular2 . While searching more I found third party library **[lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.0#isEqual)** which will do same job as angular.equals and syntax is same as angular one and this library solves my problem

Code example from lodash documentation

```
var object = { 'a': 1 };
var other = { 'a': 1 };
 
_.isEqual(object, other);
// => true
 
object === other;
// => false
```

Answer (score 22):

I rewrote Ariels answer (thank you!) to be TSLINT-friendly. You can also save some continues by using else if, but I think this is more clear. Maybe someone else needs it too:

```
export function deepEquals(x, y) {
  if (x === y) {
    return true; // if both x and y are null or undefined and exactly the same
  } else if (!(x instanceof Object) || !(y instanceof Object)) {
    return false; // if they are not strictly equal, they both need to be Objects
  } else if (x.constructor !== y.constructor) {
    // they must have the exact same prototype chain, the closest we can do is
    // test their constructor.
    return false;
  } else {
    for (const p in x) {
      if (!x.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
        continue; // other properties were tested using x.constructor === y.constructor
      }
      if (!y.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
        return false; // allows to compare x[ p ] and y[ p ] when set to undefined
      }
      if (x[p] === y[p]) {
        continue; // if they have the same strict value or identity then they are equal
      }
      if (typeof (x[p]) !== 'object') {
        return false; // Numbers, Strings, Functions, Booleans must be strictly equal
      }
      if (!deepEquals(x[p], y[p])) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    for (const p in y) {
      if (y.hasOwnProperty(p) && !x.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Most IDEs should have an "auto-format on save" option that will change code to match your linting settings automatically. On VSCode it's `"editor.formatOnSave": true`, in conjunction with `prettier` plugin (and possibly `tslint`/ `eslint`)

Comment: When I tried using this routine it returned a false positive when the two objects have a member that's a JavaScript Date type that aren't the same date.  Expect that two JS Dates should be compared using `getTime()`

Comment: This is 90% of the way there, but it doesn't handle reference loops. For example, if `foo.ref = foo` and `bar.ref = bar` this method will get stuck in an infinite loop since they both have the same structure of `{ ref: {...} }` but are referencing different instances.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of writing a function to iterate through the objects, you could just use JSON.stringify and compare the two strings?

Example:

```
var obj1 = {
  title: 'title1',
  tags: []
}

var obj2 = {
  title: 'title1',
  tags: ['r']
}


console.log(JSON.stringify(obj1));
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj2));


console.log(JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj2));
```

Comment: This works for most cases, but can fail for semantically-identical cases. E.g re-ordering the members from your example http://jsfiddle.net/9d8gjy9e/

Comment: This worked for me, as I was only comparing simple objects

Comment: as the order of members matters, such comparison is not ok

Comment: This is nice quick solution if you do not mind the edge cases where it might fail. Also, it must be enhanced if [JSON.stringify fails due to circular references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/json-stringify-avoid-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json).

Comment: This shouldn't be relied upon for any reason (except maybe a polyfill for a very old IE including an on-fail full property/value comparison for performance reasons)

Answer (score 4):

In Angular 2 you should use pure JavaScript/TypeScript for that so you can add this method to some service

```
private static equals(x, y) {
    if (x === y)
        return true;
    // if both x and y are null or undefined and exactly the same
    if (!(x instanceof Object) || !(y instanceof Object))
        return false;
    // if they are not strictly equal, they both need to be Objects
    if (x.constructor !== y.constructor)
        return false;
    // they must have the exact same prototype chain, the closest we can do is
    // test there constructor.

    let p;
    for (p in x) {
        if (!x.hasOwnProperty(p))
            continue;
        // other properties were tested using x.constructor === y.constructor
        if (!y.hasOwnProperty(p))
            return false;
        // allows to compare x[ p ] and y[ p ] when set to undefined
        if (x[p] === y[p])
            continue;
        // if they have the same strict value or identity then they are equal
        if (typeof (x[p]) !== "object")
            return false;
        // Numbers, Strings, Functions, Booleans must be strictly equal
        if (!RXBox.equals(x[p], y[p]))
            return false;
    }
    for (p in y) {
        if (y.hasOwnProperty(p) && !x.hasOwnProperty(p))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What's RXBox ??

Comment: https://medium.com/@ariel.henryson/angular-2-state-store-strategy-using-rxbox-62eaf3251e90#.uta4kv9lm  

RXBox -> It's a library I wrote to handle store inside Angular app the function here is part of the library.

Comment: To clarify, `RXBox.equals` is the qualified name of this method; it's recursive.

Answer (score 3):

You could just copy the original source code from angularjs for the angular.equals function. Usage: equals(obj1, obj2);

```
var toString = Object.prototype.toString;

function isDefined(value) {return typeof value !== 'undefined';}
function isFunction(value) {return typeof value === 'function';}
function createMap() {
  return Object.create(null);
}
function isWindow(obj) {
  return obj && obj.window === obj;
}
function isScope(obj) {
  return obj && obj.$evalAsync && obj.$watch;
}
function isRegExp(value) {
  return toString.call(value) === '[object RegExp]';
}
function simpleCompare(a, b) { return a === b || (a !== a && b !== b); }
function isDate(value) {
  return toString.call(value) === '[object Date]';
}
function isArray(arr) {
  return Array.isArray(arr) || arr instanceof Array;
}
function equals(o1, o2) {
  if (o1 === o2) return true;
  if (o1 === null || o2 === null) return false;
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-self-compare
  if (o1 !== o1 && o2 !== o2) return true; // NaN === NaN
  var t1 = typeof o1, t2 = typeof o2, length, key, keySet;
  if (t1 === t2 && t1 === 'object') {
    if (isArray(o1)) {
      if (!isArray(o2)) return false;
      if ((length = o1.length) === o2.length) {
        for (key = 0; key < length; key++) {
          if (!equals(o1[key], o2[key])) return false;
        }
        return true;
      }
    } else if (isDate(o1)) {
      if (!isDate(o2)) return false;
      return simpleCompare(o1.getTime(), o2.getTime());
    } else if (isRegExp(o1)) {
      if (!isRegExp(o2)) return false;
      return o1.toString() === o2.toString();
    } else {
      if (isScope(o1) || isScope(o2) || isWindow(o1) || isWindow(o2) ||
        isArray(o2) || isDate(o2) || isRegExp(o2)) return false;
      keySet = createMap();
      for (key in o1) {
        if (key.charAt(0) === '$' || isFunction(o1[key])) continue;
        if (!equals(o1[key], o2[key])) return false;
        keySet[key] = true;
      }
      for (key in o2) {
        if (!(key in keySet) &&
            key.charAt(0) !== '$' &&
            isDefined(o2[key]) &&
            !isFunction(o2[key])) return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = { name: 'me' }
b = { name: 'me' }
a == b // false
a === b // false
JSON.stringify(a) == JSON.stringify(b) // true
JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b) // true
```

Comment: This fails for objects where properties are defined in different order. See [his demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/w72ax3tL/)

Comment: property order is not guaranteed. Object are essentially hashtables, which shouldn't guarantee order.