# How to access the angular global in a ionic 2 application?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to to this `angular.equals(some_object, {})` inside an Ionic 2/3 application, but it cannot find the name `angular`. Basically I want to check is an object is empty using the built in angular `equals` method

Any ideas how to import it / access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ionic2++ is based on new Angular framework, that has no such implementation. If you want to compare an object with an empty use Typescript, that has an abstraction for Object.is, same as ES6:

```
Object.is(object, {})
```

[ES6: Object.is](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method in `angular`. You can use [**loadash**](https://lodash.com/) which will do the same job as `angular.equals`. See the below sample.

[**From the doc**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#isEqual):

```
var object = { 'a': 1 };
var other = { 'a': 1 };

_.isEqual(object, other);
// => true

object === other;
// => false
```

Comment: You are completely wrong. There's such method in Angular v1.x https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.equals.

Comment: well, yeah, looks like angular 2 and whatnot doesn't have it. too bad. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40597658/equivalent-of-angular-equals-in-angular2

Comment: @Fals that documentation was for angular 1 not angular 2.

Comment: @atulquest93 read carefully, what is written. the methos exists where? Angular v1.x

Comment: op is asking for IONIC2 .. don't confuse him

Comment: @atulquest93 Say that something doesn't exist isn't the same as that exists in a previous version. Also, you can compare with pure TypeScript, there's no need to introduce another lib for this

Comment: @Fals ionic2/3 uses angular 2+ not angular v1

Comment: When you're dealing with the multiple platforms it is recommended to use generic libraries rather than using vanilla javascript. Since those libraries have all the fixes for different browsers,versions and etc. @Fals

Comment: Typescript is a super set of javascript. Your solution was ok, but why a lib when you already have this available in Typescript? Libs are cool, but they are not always the way to go.

Comment: May be you don't have any working experince with the cross platfrom mobile app developments.Plain `JS/TS` doesn't support all the browsers. But library does. That is why it recomended always. Another good exaple is `Momentjs`. @Fals